# Error while installing an ejs Template engine,

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am getting this error while installing ejs as node is not recognized,but in system variable it is present.what to do..
$ npm install ejs

> node --harmony ./postinstall.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN contact_list@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! ejs@3.1.3 postinstall: `node --harmony ./postinstall.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the ejs@3.1.3 postinstall script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!
 C:\Users\SM185585\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-28T13_08_27_678Z-debug.log

Comment: You should format the log and also explain a bit more about it